# Unit test doesn't work as expected on second run

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit, jdbctemplate

I have two tests units one is to  insert a record in a database, the second one is to delete a record from a database
note: I'm using oracle 11g express edition.

I run the insert test unit and it works as expected, it insert a record in the database, then I run the second test unit and delete the record from the database.

Now when I run the insert test unit again it don't work it fails in the part when I call a searchById method with the I'd that I just inserted, what is casuing this beahaviour

Note: I pass the number 3 as a parameter because my table have two records by default.

Here is the code for the unit test:

```
@Test
public void insertUser() 
{

    userDAO.insertUser();
    User testUser =  userDAO.searchUserById(3);
    assertNotNull(testUser);
}

@Test
public void deleteUser() 
{

    userDAO.deleteUserById(3);
    User nullUser  =  userDAO.searchUserById(3);
    assertNull(nullUser);
}
```

And here is the code of the methods:

Here is the searchById method:

```
    @Override
public User searchUserById(int userId) 
{
    User user=  null;
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        String storedProcedure  =  "{ call searchUserById(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";

        connection  =  jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(storedProcedureInfoUsuario);

        callableStatement.setInt(1, userId);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);

        callableStatement.executeQuery();

        //
        user=  new User();
        usuario.setName(callableStatement.getString(2));
        usuario.setLastName(callableStatement.getString(3));
        usuario.setEmail(callableStatement.getString(4));
        usuario.setState(callableStatement.getString(5));
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
//          
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            if(connection != null)
            try 
            {
                connection.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
```

And here is the insert method:

```
@Override
    public User insertUser(User user) 
    {

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            String storedProcedure  =  "{ call insertUser(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";

            connection  =  jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(storedProcedureInfoUsuario);

            callableStatement.setInt(1, userId);
            callableStatement.setString(2, user.getName());
            callableStatement.setString(3, user.getLastName());
            callableStatement.setString(4, user.getEmail());
            callableStatement.setString(5, user.getState());

            callableStatement.executeQuery();

            //
            user=  new User();
            usuario.setName(callableStatement.getString(2));
            usuario.setLastName(callableStatement.getString(3));
            usuario.setEmail(callableStatement.getString(4));
            usuario.setState(callableStatement.getString(5));
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
    //          
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally 
            {
                if(connection != null)
                try 
                {
                    connection.close();
                } 
                catch (SQLException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return user;
        }
```

Here is the delete method:

```
 @Override
public void deleteUserById(int idUser)
{

    Connection connection = null;
    try {

        String storedProcedure =  "{ call deleteUserById(?) }";

        connection  =  jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(storedProcedureBorrarUSuario);

        callableStatement.setInt(1, idUser);

        callableStatement.executeQuery();
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        if(connection != null)
        try 
        {
            connection.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stored procedure **searchUserById**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE searchUserById
    (
       p_userId IN User.user_id%TYPE,
       ps_name OUT User.name%TYPE,
       ps_lastName OUT User.lastName%TYPE,
       ps_email OUT User.email%TYPE,
       ps_state OUT User.state%TYPE
    )
IS
BEGIN

  SELECT name, lastName, email, state
  INTO ps_name , ps_lastName , ps_email , ps_state 
  FROM  USER WHERE user_id= p_userid;

END;
/
```

and here is the insert pl sql

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertUser
    (

       ps_name IN User.name%TYPE,
       ps_lastName IN User.lastName%TYPE,
       ps_email IN User.email%TYPE,
       ps_state IN User.state%TYPE
    )
IS
BEGIN

  Insert into User 
  (userId,name, lastname, email, state)
  Values
  (user_sq.nextval(), ps_name,  ps_lastName , ps_email , ps_state )
 COMMIT;
END;
/
```

and here is my delete PL/SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deleteUserById
    (
       p_userId IN USER.user_ID%TYPE
    )
IS
BEGIN

  DELETE FROM USER
  WHERE user_id=p_userId;
COMMIT;
END;
```

What is causing this behavior, I run them separately and both methods work, is just that when I run the insert test for the second time it returns null in the search by I'd method, why is that method returning null is I just inserted a record, and why this method works the first time but not the second time after I run my delete test

Here is the workflow of my problem:

```
1) I run the insert test,
2) I check that the user was inserted
3) I run my delete test, 
4) I check that the user was deleted from the table
5) I run again my test method and it fails, it can't find the user that was inserted in the code line above by the insertUser method
```

Note all the methods where ran separately, and if I want to make the test to work for the first time after they stop working, I have to delete all the records in the table and insert them again by a insert script that I run in the sqlplus console.

Comment: Are you relying on the outcome of one test to affect another? i.e. are you relying on the insert test to setup a user that the delete test can delete? Avoid having tests depend on each other, as you can't guarantee they'll always run in the same order. Best thing to do is setup data in a setup() method

Comment: the user pojo is fill by my setud() options, after mi user pojo setup is complete i inserted the pojo using my insert method, 

and i can guarantee that my insert test is executed firts since i'm executing each test separately. in netbeans by choosing the option run selected test

Comment: I think the state that each test is leaving the DB in is unpredictable. Your tests are relying on data in a specific state in order to run. If tests run in a different order, or 1 test fails then you run it again, who knows what "users" you'll have there. The best piece of advice I can give is to treat every test case as if there is *nothing* there already. If you want to delete a user, make sure it is there to start with. If you want to add a user, make sure no others exist with the same details (avoid a conflict). Clear data before each test and insert ONLY what the test requires to pass

Comment: In the userDAO insertUser method what is the value of `userId` field in the `callableStatement.setInt(1, userId);` ?